# Class method that does not require instantiated class object

Tags: php, class, methods

So here's the class with the method today(). Is it possible to call today() without requiring an instantiated class object to run it?

i.e. without using MyDateClass::today()

```
<?php
    Class MyDateClass
    {
        public $mm;
        public $dd;
        public $yyyy;

        function __construct($mm, $dd, $yyyy)
        {
            $this->mm = $mm;
            $this->dd = $dd;
            $this->yyyy = $yyyy;
        }

        function today()
        {
            return date('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: no, read the question again

Comment: @Dagon *.............NO* sounds pretty correct to me :)

Comment: that's because it is correct ;-)

Comment: haha, yeah its late, missed that one word "without" ;D

Comment: i guess he could just use echo  `date('Y-m-d')` ;-)

Comment: @Dagon Nah, that would be too simple

Comment: I think the question needs to be rephrased, according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), `Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class.` , so technically doing  `MyDateClass::today()`, is calling the function without instantiating a class.

Comment: If you have to use classes for dates, why not use PHP's built-in DateTime classes rather than write your own?

Comment: Thanks @mdodong I think that cleared things up for me

Comment: @mdodong - except you have to define the method as static for that, or suppress those horrible warning thingys that tell you that you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

`MyDateClass::today()` - this means you call a static method and static methods do not create an instance of a class unless there is a code which creates an instance. But your `today()` is not static(no `static` word).

Static function is more like a simple function than a class method.

```
Class MyDateClass
{
    public $mm;
    public $dd;
    public $yyyy;
    public $timestamp;

    function __construct($mm, $dd, $yyyy)
    {
        $this->mm = $mm;
        $this->dd = $dd;
        $this->yyyy = $yyyy;
    }
    function printDate(){
        echo $this->dd.'.'.$this->mm.'.'.$this->yyyy;
    }
    static function today()
    {
        return date('Y-m-d');
    }
}
MyDateClass::today(); // no instance
$instance1 = new MyDateClass('01','05','2015'); //instance1
$instance2 = new MyDateClass('01','05','2014'); //instance2
$instance1->printDate(); // prints 05.01.2015
$instance2->printDate(); // prints 05.01.2014
```

Comment: Sounds good, I think the question wasn't phrased clearly. Thanks!